# I did not understand what is happening with int array in my code

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int marks[40] = {83, 86, 97, 83, 93, 83, 86, 52, 49, 41, 42, 47, 90, 59, 63, 86, 40, 46, 92, 56, 51, 48, 67, 49, 42, 90, 42, 83, 47, 95, 69, 82, 82, 58, 69, 67, 53, 56, 71, 62};

    int i,j,count[101],tm;

    for(i=0;i<101;i++)
    {
        count[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        tm=marks[i];
        count[tm]=count[tm]+1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
    {
       if(count[i]!=0)
       {
            printf("Marks: %d count: %d\n",i,count[i]);
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. I did not understand in this here.

[image]

first `i=0`, `marks[i]`, `marks[0]` means `marks[0]=83`
so
 `tm=marks[0]=83`
and then 
`count[tm]=count[tm]+1;`
And I did not understand in this line.

Comment: Updating the histogram (frequency table). What else do you think it is?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: count[tm]=count[tm]+1;

Comment: count[tm]=count[83]+1; count[83]=???

Comment: You do not understand the code you wrote? :-S

Comment: Isn't that to count the number of people with certain marks?

Comment: I did not understand just that line how to count use this count array?

Comment: Maybe it's time to open your C textbook.

Comment: @asad : Refer @Mohit Jain's comment. That is what you are looking for. `count[tm]`  will hold the frequency of `marks` or number of times that given mark is repeated.

Comment: Copying code from a site, or another student, then asking us to explain it, is not really helping anyone:(   It's obviously not 'my code'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some comments to your code such that you can easier understand what is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) // use void if your function has no parameters
{
    int marks[] = {83, 86, 97, 83, 93, 83, 86, 52, 49, 41, 42, 47, 90, 59, 63, 86, 40, 46, 92, 56, 51, 48, 67, 49, 42, 90, 42, 83, 47, 95, 69, 82, 82, 58, 69, 67, 53, 56, 71, 62}; // you can leave out the array size if you instantiate it afterwards

    int i, tm; // j is never used, so leave it out
    int count[101]; // count[i] tells you in the end how often the mark i occured in the marks array

    for(i=0; i < 101; i++) // initialize the count array with zeros
    {
        count[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<40;i++) // loop over the marks array and increment thhe count array at the current mark position by one
    {
        tm=marks[i];
        count[tm]=count[tm]+1; // increment the count of mark i by one
    }
    // marks[i] tells you how often i appears in the marks array -> marks is a frequency table
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++) // print out how often a mark appeared, but only if it appeared at least once
    {
       if(count[i]!=0)
       {
            printf("Marks: %d count: %d\n",i,count[i]);
       }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `count[tm]=count[tm]+1; // increment the count of mark i by one` How is this comment helpful? This is completely redundant. Many people who don't even understand any of the `C` dialect would get it.

Comment: @MohitJain For me it seems that is new to C and maybe programming at all. I thought it might be helpful for him to add a more abstract description of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines

```
tm=marks[i];
count[tm]=count[tm]+1;
```

do the following:

1. get the value stored in `marks[i]`
2. store the value pulled in 1. into `tm`
3. get the value of `count[tm]`
4. add `1` to what had been pulled in 3.
5. store the result of the addition done in 4. into `count[tm]`, overwriting the value that had been pulled in 3..

By adding 1 in step 4, you are counting the number of occurrences of a specific mark.